# How Android application framework communicates with Libraries?

Tags: android

From Android architecture, application framework (Content Providers,Resource manager. etc) are written in Java. But the libraries(Surface Manager, 3D libraries etc) are in C.
One user asked this, and nobody replied. I do not have enough reputation to comment on that question, so I need to post question again.

Answer (score 0):

Like other apps it uses Java Native Interface (JNI) to access native code.

Answer (score 0):

The [Java Native Interface](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html) - although you'll probably [don't need it](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#NativeMethods) for most apps.